# my android device is not listed under the adb devices in command prompt

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

my android is  7.0 and my windows machine is running on 8.1
i turned on all the settings from the mobile for usb debugging and then connected to my pc.
when i entered the command `adb devices` in command prompt as administrator , my device is not listed under **List of devices attached**

Comment: Did you notice "allow usb debugging" popup in phone ? If not then change the data cable.

Comment: ASSALAMU ALAIKUM bro. thanks for replying . i didn't get "allow usb debugging" in my phone and i also changed different data cables. but , in my brother's pc , my phone asks for that permission. i want to cast and control my android using this method ------>>>>   https://youtu.be/k8SiUx1JRMw

Comment: Install usb driver based on your Phone company. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers , follow the link